# Regular expression to find $ signs but not ones with {} around them

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to escape $ signs that are not surrounded by {}.

This is what I have so far: `\^\$|[^\{]\$\`

```
$test
```

expected: match actual: match

```
{$test1}
```

expected: no match actual: no match

```
{$test}  $test1
```

expected: match 2nd actual: matches space before 2nd $ sign

```
{ $test3 }
```

expected: no match actual: matches space before $ sign

So basically if a $ is enclosed by brackets, it should never match, but any other $ should match.

I'm using php and I'm assuming there is no nesting of brackets.There can be whitespace (n spaces or linebreaks or tabs, any kind of whitespace) between brackets and $ signs.

Comment: Which language/environment/tool are you using this regex in?

Comment: Can brackets be nested or not?

Comment: Search for regex parentheses -- there where lots of similar questions on SO...

Comment: I'm using php, and I'm assuming that brackets cannot be nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you assuming no nested parentheses

`$result = preg_replace('/\$(?![^{]*\})/m', '', $subject);`

Explanation

```
"
\$         # Match the character “$” literally
(?!        # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   [^{]       # Match any character that is NOT a “{”
      *          # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   }          # Match the character “}” literally
)
"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about: `\^(?:{[^}]*}|[^{])*\$\`
the substitute with `$1\\$`

Comment: I think above fails for this string "test {$ pd } ds $tsh"